# How to call another activity after certain time

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

At this moment I try to create an Android TV application.

For example, I have 3 activities. I would like to call another activity after 10 seconds. How can I create this using `Android C#`?

```
Activity 1
---------- (after 10 sec) ->
Activity 2
---------- (after 10 sec) ->
Activity 3
---------- (after 10 sec) -> AGAIN to Activity 1
```

What is the best way to solve this?

Comment: Do you have some example using Timer within Android C#?

Comment: using handler you can do this but in core android .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution for this. You have to use Threading.

```
new Thread(new ThreadStart(() =>
                                 {
        Thread.Sleep(10000);
        RunOnUiThread(() =>
                      {
          Intent i = new Intent();
          i.SetClass(this, typeof(Activity2));
          StartActivity(i);

          this.Finish();
        });


      })).Start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use AlaramManager to set the timing of the activity when to call.

```
Intent intentA=new Intent(context, A.class);

pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intentA, 0);

alarmManager=(AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,0,3000, pendingIntent);


Intent intentB=new Intent(context, B.class);

pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intentB, 0);

alarmManager=(AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,1000,3000, pendingIntent);


Intent intentC=new Intent(context, C.class);

pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, intentC, 0);

alarmManager=(AlarmManager)getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);

alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,2000,3000, pendingIntent);
```

I haven't tried it but it i think it would with little modification.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm looking for C# solution. :(

Answer (score 0):

Use no of Handlers to achieve this.Here this activity starts after 2 seconds

```
     Handler handler = new Handler();
               Runnable r=new Runnable() {
                         @Override
                         public void run() {
                           startActivity(new intent(xxx.this,yyy.class);
                         }         
                       };
                   handler.postDelayed(r, 2000);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm looking for C# solution. :(