# How to move from one activity to another after certain time automatically in C#

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, android-activity, xamarin.android

I need to move from 1st activity to 2nd activity with a sleep of 5 seconds before moving to 2nd activity. My first activity contains an image which is rotating using the below code -

`ImageForRotation.StartAnimation(loadedImage)`

And the second activity is a login page. Here is my code -

```
base.OnCreate(bundle);
SetContentView(Resource.Layout.SplashScreen);
ImageView ImageForRotation = FindViewById < ImageView > (Resource.Id.imageForRotation);

var loadedImage = AnimationUtils.LoadAnimation(this, Resource.Animation.SplashScreenImageRotation);

ImageForRotation.StartAnimation(loadedImage);
//here the code for 5 second wait time which i don't know
StartActivity(typeof(LoginScreen)); //second activity
```

Answer (score 2):

Like this , this is your first activity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       NextActivity();
}

public void NextActivity()
{   
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable(){
        @Override
        public void run() {

            Intent mainIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Main2Activity.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(mainIntent);
            MainActivity.this.finish();
        }
    }, 5000);

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16314177/how-to-call-another-activity-after-certain-time

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you want to wait for 5 sec but if you want to launch **LoginScreen** after the completion of animation, then you can achieve this by **setAnimationListener** method.

Here is the details about it:

```
public void setAnimationListener(Animation.AnimationListener listener)
```

It binds an animation listener to this animation. The animation listener is notified of animation events such as the end of the animation or the repetition of the animation.

Parameters:

**listener** - the animation listener to be notified

Comment: cannot convert from 'AECS.SplashScreen' to 'Android.Views.Animations.Animation.IAnimationListener'

Comment: here code:        loadedImage.SetAnimationListener(this);

Answer (score 0):

```
SetContentView(Resource.Layout.SplashScreen);
   ImageView ImageForRotation = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageForRotation);

    var loadedImage = AnimationUtils.LoadAnimation(this,Resource.Animation.SplashScreenImageRotation);


    ImageForRotation.StartAnimation(loadedImage);
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
    StartActivity(typeof(LoginScreen)); //second activity
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a Handler to switch to the next activity after a specific time interval (say 5000 ms )

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        /*
         * Showing your animation screen with a timer. This will be useful when you
         * want to show case your app logo / company
         */

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // This method will be executed once the timer is over
            // Start your app main activity
            Intent i = new Intent(CurrentScreen.this, NextActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);

            // close this activity
            finish();
        }
    }, 5000);
```

Write your animation code before adding the handler.